# How to obtain a certain range of number in my data with python

Tags: python, range

I have a set of number ranging from 0 to 180

I want to iron out the difference close to 180 and 90

With the code

```
ironed = []
for pred in Result.values[:,3]:
    if 160 < pred < 200 or -20 < pred < 20:
        ironed.append(180)
        if 80 < pred <100:
            ironed.append(90)
    else: ironed.append(pred)
```

I can iron out the number close to 180 and 0 and append 180 for that

But the second "if 80 < pred <100:" is not working.

How to make the second "if" work?

Comment: What do you mean by "iron", could you clarify what this code is doing, and can you provide the input data please?

Comment: If your data ranges from `0 to 180` what's the point of `-20 < pred < 20`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ironed = []
for pred in Result.values[:,3]:
    if 160 < pred < 200 or -20 < pred < 20:
        ironed.append(180)
    elif 80 < pred <100:
            ironed.append(90)
    else: ironed.append(pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second 'if' is indented incorrectly, it is in the first if's block. So it is only running if the first if's condition is true. So do this:

```
ironed = []
for pred in Result.values[:,3]:
    if 160 < pred < 200 or -20 < pred < 20:
        ironed.append(180)
    if 80 < pred <100:
        ironed.append(90)
    else: ironed.append(pred)
```

Also, I expect you want the 'else' to work if none of the above conditions are true, but in this case if the first 'if' executes but the second doesn't, the 'else' will still execute. To fix that, you should use an 'elif' instead of the second 'if', like this:

```
ironed = []
for pred in Result.values[:,3]:
    if 160 < pred < 200 or -20 < pred < 20:
        ironed.append(180)
    elif 80 < pred <100:
        ironed.append(90)
    else: ironed.append(pred)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never hit the second if statement. Your first if statement:

```
if 160 < pred < 200 or -20 < pred < 20:
```

Is saying check **if** my prediction is in the range 160 to 200 **or** in the range -20 to 20. Because of this you will never get a number in between 80 and 100 because you've excluded that range with your first statement.